# Is it good practice to nest bootstrap grid inside smaller elements on the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap responsive grid system only as I need only that from whole framework.
I understand that I should use grid system only for layout of the page.
But for example I have one `div` that should contain image on the left and some text on the right side.
I can put bootstrap grid inside that `div` to get desired layout as that is just two columns.
Is this how bootstrap grid should be used or this is bad practice and I shouldn't use grid inside smaller elements?
[image]

Comment: I would say this is fine, I've done this a few times. Just make sure that its graceful when you scale down through the screen widths. Also, if you are bothered about ie7 (who is these days?) make sure you do something about the box-sizing. Also, this would be tricky for the later versions of bootstap as you didn't have the option of adding the classes for smaller widths at different breakpoints. But, I guess your using the latest version. Other than that... I can't see a problem - but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Sure it's fine.. and it's the basis of grid nesting: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 0):

It is fine as long as you place grid elements in the right order of hierarchy:

`container[-fluid]` > `row` > `col-??-##` > `row` > `col-??-##` and so on.

Remember to NEVER nest a `container` inside another `container`. You should not place a `container` immediately followed by a `col` element.

All in all, it's ok to give layout to the inner part of your div regardless of its size.